# How to access the same view in different tabs

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I'm quite new to Swift and was hoping someone would help me figure out a little something about Navigation.

I have a Tab Bar Controller with four tabs, each with its own Navigation Controller. I was wondering what is the best way to access a "common" view from any of those tabs without navigating to a different tab.

Think about the Twitter app: I can access the view that displays an user's profile info from the "Home" tab, from the "Search" tab or even from the "Notifications" tab, and when I click the back button, it will pop this "common" view controller from the current tab's navigation controller's stack and return to the current tab's previous view. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Make a new instance of the view controller (eg ProfileViewController in your example) and push it on to the appropriate navigation controller’s stack.

Comment: But how would I design that in the storyboard? Would it be a separate View Controller with no connection to any of the navigation controllers I have for each tab?

Comment: You can have multiple navigation controllers point to the same "common view". Or you could have nothing connected to it and instantiate programmatically. It sounds like you might be more comfortable with the first option.

Answer (score 1):

@JarWarren, I was indeed looking to do it in the storyboard, but I managed to do it programmatically, following Aaron's suggestion:

I created the ProfileViewController and didn't link it to any of the navigation controllers, then I assigned a value to its "Storyboard ID" property, so that I would be able to instantiate the view controller with **storyboard.instantiateViewController**.

```
guard let profileViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ProfileViewController") as? ProfileViewController else {
    fatalError("Unable to instantiate view controller with provided identifier.")
}
    
navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
```

Thank you both for helping me out.